# PHP upload limited

Tags: php, ajax, file-upload

I have an ajax form where I am trying to upload a 30MB PDF.
When I upload a file upto 10MB the file upload correctly but when I attempt to upload a file larger than 10MB the file is not uploaded properly, when I look into the C:\windows\temp file I can see the file is uploading but once it hits between 8-10MB a new temp file it created when this 2nd file hits about 8MB the files stops uploading.

The loaded PHP settings are as follows:-
Version: 5.2.17

```
max_execution_time = 3600  
max_input_time = 3600  
memory_limit = 1024M  
post_max_size = 5G  
upload_max_filesize = 5G
```

Has anybody had this problem before?
How am I able to fix this issue?

Comment: Have you checked how your webserver is configured? (you did't say which webserver it is).

Comment: Are you sure those are your local settings also? Might want to run `phpinfo()` to make sure.

Comment: Its a windows server 2008 R2 running IIS 11.5 you can access the phpinfo file via http://flipbook.phpcore.co.uk/info.php

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using 5G try 5000M and has your server got enough space/RAM to do this, a server is a modified pc remember if not try this in a .htaccess file php_value post_max_size 1000M etc